# Load testing microservice - bad results

Tags: performance, spring-boot, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, load-testing

I am struggling with the results of a load test of my api service.
The service is deployed on GCP. There are 2 instances running behind a nginx.

I am using spring boot 2.0 with default tomcat configuration.
The service is running inside a docker container with -Xmx768M

A request to the tested endpoint fetches a single row from a database and returns it.

My results:

> ab -c 1 -n 1 /testapi

```
Requests per second: 15
Time per request: 63ms
```

> ab -c 10 -n 100 /testapi

```
Requests per second: 102
Time per request: 97ms
```

> ab -c 50 -n 100 /testapi

```
Requests per second: 95
Time per request: 522ms
```

> ab -c 100 -n 100 /testapi

```
Requests per second: 93
Time per request: 1065ms
```

> ab -c 200 -n 200 /testapi

```
Timeout
```

**Worrying aspects:**

- Heap usage is rising after each test
- At 99.99% heap usage I am getting slow responses until the container crashes with  *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*
- I am able to ddos 2 instances of an API from a single laptop.

What am I doing wrong here? Does the tomcat configuration needs further tweaking? Are the JVM parameters wrong?

Thanks

EDIT tested code:

```
@ApiOperation(value="Get Device", response = Device.class, authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "Authorization")})
@RequestMapping(value="/device/commnr/{commnr}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> getDevice(@PathVariable String commnr) {

    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> deferred = new DeferredResult<>();

    HttpServletRequest request = getCurrentHttpRequest();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(deferred.isSetOrExpired()) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            } else {
                User user = authenticationService.loginUser(request);

                Device device = deviceService.findByCommNr(commnr);
                if(!AuthTools.isUserDevice(device, user)) {
                    deferred.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>("Requested Device does not belong to user.", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
                }

                if(device == null) {
                    deferred.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
                }

                deferred.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(device, HttpStatus.OK));
            }
        }
    }, 10);

    return deferred;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring WebFlux?

Comment: I added the code from the tested method.

Comment: You should take and analyze a memory snapshot using tools like Memory Analyzer (MAT) or VisualVM. It's kind of hard to guess which class instances are leaking.